# I use iOS LightBlue to connect Android simulator peripheral, and the iPhone shows that timeout interrogating the peripheral

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a problem is that when I use the iPhone to connect the Android BLE Simulator by Lightblue. I click the Lightblue item to connect the Android BLE simulator. After a few minutes, it shows Timeout interrogating the peripheral in the iPhone Lightblue.

PS: Lightblue can search the simulator BLE peripheral.

I use this project from github.com.

https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/ble-test-peripheral-android

Comment: will you post the lightblue and BLE peripheral log please.

Comment: Thank you ,and I had solve the problem code by myself.maybe it cause by Lightblue. As I use the iPhone to connect other devices , the same situation occur. sorry for my poor english.

Comment: strange; then you may report an issue to lightblue :-)

Comment: Thank you,I will do it after my work.